# How to achieve equal height image columns that shrinks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve a grid-like layout where every column in a row has the same height. Each column contains a picture so it must also keep the proportions of the image.

The current solution is to set the flex-grow property to the ratio of the image. This works but can result in very large images which is not desired in my case.

[image]

I would like the images to shrink to fit on one row in the case of negative space left.

[image]

The flex-shrink property works similar to the flow-grow property. The negative space will be distributed between the items based on the flex-shrink property.

However there is a caveat in the flex-shrink behaviour: the item will never shrink to a size less than the content of it. In my case that means the column will never shrink to a size less than the images it contains.

I can work around the problem by setting the flex-basis property to a smaller value. I've played around with this but either messed up the wrapping or the equal heights.

What I would like to happen:

Consider the following markup:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
}

.img-container {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1;" class="img-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
  </div>
  
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1;" class="img-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
  </div>

  <div style="flex-grow: 2; flex-shrink: 2;" class="img-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/" alt=""> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The sum of the width is 200+200+400=800px which means there is 800-600=200px negative space. The flex-shrink values dictates that item one and two gets 1 part of the negative space and that item three gets 2 parts.

Calculating this gives us:

- Width to remove from item one: 1/4*200=50
- Width to remove from item two: 1/4*200=50
- Width to remove from item three: 2/4*200=100

These widths are correct and would keep the correct ratios but as I mentioned earlier this cannot be achieved since the flex-basis is the natural width of the image elements.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: *However there is a caveat in the flex-shrink behaviour: the item will never shrink to a size less than the content of it. In my case that means the column will never shrink to a size less than the images it contains.* ==> because it is an image and you have set `width: 100%`, the divs can even shrink to zero, and you wouldn't have to set `min-width: 0` too...

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of your `.container` and the height of your `.img-container` it should work.

Now you only have to decide how you want to space your images. `.container { justify-content: space-evenly/space-between/space-around}`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.img-container {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/" alt=""> 
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/" alt=""> 
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/" alt=""> 
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/" alt="">     
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat! Ideally I need the wrapping in my case though.

Comment: @EmricMånsson You said you want them to be in one row. Why do you need wrap then?

Comment: In my use case there is an indefinite number of pictures. I wan't about 4 pictures on each row and keep their proportions. With the current solution it will look like in the first picture I posted. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @EmricMånsson Allright. I have edited the answer to hopefully achieve what you need.